# Validar un formulario con los datos en .serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Como puedo validar que los campos de mi formulario estén llenos después de utilizar  **.serialize()** para capturar todos los datos de mi formulario. Tenia pensado usar un **if** para esto pero no funciono.

```
$("#formcashier").on("submit" , function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //var datos=$(this).serialize()
    var datos = $('#formcashier').serialize();
    if(datos == ""){
        Swal.fire({
            icon:'error',
            title:'No hay datos ingresados!',});
            return false;
     }
```

Comment: var datos = document.getElementById("formcashier");

Comment: debajo de la linea del serialize() escribe `alert(datos);` y a ver que te sale. O bien un  `console.log(datos)` y lo miras en consola.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, pero creo que no me hice entender muy bien con respecto a mi cuestión, lo que sucede es que quiero saber si cuando se  da click en el botón enviar, las cajas del formulario están vacías o no,  y en caso de que esten vacías salte un **alert: No ha ingresado datos**,  ya que use el **.serialize();** para llevar todos los datos a una base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo el serialize los datos como tal, intenta hacerlo asi

```
var datos = document.getElementById("formcashier");
datos=datos.serialize();
```